# Can a class constructor be called from a method?

Tags: c++, class, methods, constructor

If I have the following a class:

```
class A {
private:
    int *x;
public:
    A() { x = new int; *(A::x) = 0; }
    A(const int *y) { x = new int; *(A::x) = *y; }
    ~A() { delete x; }
    void operator = (const int *y) { A(y); }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    int y = 3;
    a = &y;

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the assignment statement to call the `=` method, which in turn will set the `x` member via calling the respective constructor. However, it seems like after the assignment, the value of `x` is still `NULL` and the value of `y` was not assigned over.

So, is calling the constructor from a method a defined operation? If so, what do I miss in my code? Using the debugger I verified that the constructor is actually being *called* it's just that the copied values are not retained once the flow returns from the constructor the the `=` method.

Comment: @dyp No, it doesn't. It would create a local variable named `y` of type `A`, not a temporary, except that it's an error in C++ to have a local variable at the function-top-level with the same name as a function parameter.

Comment: @dyp - OK, so does this mean I cannot call the constructor from a  method?

Comment: @KerrekSB - thanks. That is very constructive.

Comment: `void operator = (const int *y) { A(y); }` should be at least `A&  operator = (const int *y) { A(y); return *this; }` and `A(y);` doesn't make sense (it's a local function declaration actually).

Comment: @hvd D'oh, I fell for it - again. :(

Comment: @ysap That's sort of right. You cannot call a constructor for an already-initialised object, not even `*this`. The behaviour you're seeing, though, is not the behaviour I would have expected from any implementation.

Comment: @hvd - thanks. Can you make this an answer, so there's better "peer review", and I can accept that?

Comment: @ysap in regards to the constructor and debbuger, when you break in constructor, make sure you know which object that constructor belongs to. I.e. (for visual studio) in the "watch" type "this" - this will show you the address of you current object. You will see that the construct is firing from not the same object that you apparently expect.

Comment: @ysap I'm still trying to figure out what's actually happening. If there's no good answer by the time I've figured that out, I'll make an attempt at posting an answer.

Comment: Apparently, two voters voted t close this question as being off-topic to SO... WTF? Care to explain how a clear programming question, that includes an executable example, is off-topic here?

Comment: @ysap, try reading the specific reason given, it explains it clearly.

Comment: @JonathanWakely - The reason is "off-topic", which I fail to see how. Anyway, I asked about that here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280382/274579

Comment: Either look at the value of `this` in each constructor using your debugger, or just add `std::cout << this << ": " << *x << '\n';` in various places in the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Constructors are used to create an object, you cannot call them again on an existing object.

Objects begin their lifetime once, and end their lifetime (at most) once. What you are trying to do would be like being born twice, which sounds messy.

Answer (score 2):

When you call a constructor like you did, it is interpreted as an expression, that creates an anonymous object of class A.  This anonymous object is destroyed at the end of the statement in which it was created.   So nothing happens.

I propose you the following change:

```
class A {
private:
    int *x;
public:
    A() { x = new int; *x = 0; }    // No need of A:: 
    A(const int *y) { x = new int; *x = *y; }
    ~A() { delete x; }
    A& operator= (const int *y) { *x=*y; return *this;  } // x was already iniatilized, so we keep it
};
```

But in fact, you don't need pointers here, so you can simplify further:

```
class A {
private:
    int x;
public:
    A() :x(0) { }  
    A(int y) : x(y) { }
    ~A() { }
    A& operator= (const int y) { x=y; return *this;  } 
};
```

***Edit:***

In the comment you explained that you need pointers and that your intent was to avoid duplication of code.   I then propose you another alternative.

As said, you cannot  call the constructor in `operator=()`.  But you are allowed to do the contrary according to the standard (section 12.7/4: *Member functions, including virtual functions, can be called during construction or destruction*).  You could then combine this with the delegate constructor mechanism:

```
A(const int *y) : A() { *this = y; }   // calls default constructor and then uses assignment to do copy.
```

Be aware however that there could be subtle difference here with the plain copy constructor, for example inf you have some reference members.

Comment: Thanks. I do need the pointers, because this is just an extract of my actual case, where I do use pointers. Your suggestion for a fix will probably work, and this is how I ended up doing it in my program (of course, with the required adaptations to my real case). But, I wanted to reuse the constructor, where I already have a similar code.

Comment: @ysap Ok !  I've made an edit that proposes an other alternative to reuse code between assignement and consturctor.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am aware of the other-way-around possibility. In this particular case it looks less appropriate, because the constructor includes more arguments in addition to just the `y` argument, and I wanted the `=` operator to be used in a very specific subset of the possible construction options. Thus, the code in the constructor is a superset of the code I ended up adding to the `=` method.

Comment: Ok ! Then you have still the option of having a private member function to share some common code between copy constructor and assignment

Comment: That's right. At this point I am satisfied with just a code duplicate. The overhead required for sharing code seems like too much to worth it.